# How could I go about checking whether the input information is contained in the user.json file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**I have a "user.json" file that looks like this**. using java script I have to parse this file and then check this email and file combinations against user input

```
{
    "something@somewhere.com": "maybe",
    "john@beatles.uk": "lennonj!",
    "paul@beatles.uk": "mccartney",
    "mick@rollingstones.uk": "jaggerm!"
}
 
function lookUpCredentials(filePath, cb) {
    fs.readFile(filePath, (err, fileData) => {
        if (err) {
            return cb && cb(err);
        }
        try {
            const object = JSON.parse(fileData);
            return cb && cb(null, object);
        } catch (err) {
            return cb && cb(err);
        }
    });
}

lookUpCredentials("./user.json", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    credentials = data;
});
 
 
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    let username = req.body.username;
    let password = req.body.password;
})
```

My question is How could I go about checking whether the input information is contained in the user.json file ?

Comment: In your code, who calls `lookUpCredentials`? And where is the `credentials` variable stored?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `lookupCredentials()` in with the handler provided to `app.post()`.
After the check you give back an answer to client via `res.send()` resp. `res.end()`. For each situation you want to stop request and give the client an answer.

The lookup and credentials check could look as follows:

```js
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {

    // If you do not change the variable later on, use const ! 
    const username = req.body.username
    const password = req.body.password

    // respond if provided parameters are not given or emtpy.
    if(!username || !password) {
        res.status(400).end('No username or No password provided.')
        return
    }

    // now use your created function to lookup the data:
    // first read in file via 
    lookUpCredentials('./user.json', (err, credentials) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err)
            // always send a response on error!
            res.status(500).end('Error when looking up credentials file.')
            return
        }


        // since you have an object with usernames as keys, we simply
        // check if there is a value in the object
        const stored_password = credentials[username]

        // when no password was found, the username was not listed! => bad username
        if(!stored_password) {
            console.error('bad username', username)
            res.status(403).end('Bad username')
            return
        }

        // Check the password!
        // when missmatched, inform client!
        if(stored_password !== password) {
            console.error('bad password received for user', username)
            res.status(403).end('Bad password')
            return
        }

        // No checks failed! We now can inform user he is logged in!
        res.status(200).end('Login succeceded for user', username)

    });
})
```